# If |f| is Riemann integrable, then f is Riemann integrable???

Tags: analysis

[image]

So i am stuck here.. how do i prove the first & second inequalities?

Also if |f| is Riemann integrable, then f is Riemann integrable.

I think it's ture but i dont know how to prove it.

any hints would be appreciated!
Thank You

Comment: The customary character to use for absolute values is `|` (if you have problems producing that with your keyboard, in $\TeX$ you can say `\vert`)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I just edited!! Thank you!

Comment: It is not true that if $|f|$ is integrable that $f$ is integrable. Take for instance the function that is $-1$ on rationals on $[0,1]$ and $+1$ on irrationals on $[0,1]$.

Comment: And wrap all your formulas in `$...$`.

Comment: @CameronWilliams hey Cameron, do you have any idea how to prove the inequalities??

Comment: What exactly is the "U" notation that is in the problem statement? I've never seen it.

Comment: @CameronWilliams same here I've never seen that before.... maybe just some integers

Comment: I'd guess a $U$ before an integral means the upper sum for a given partition.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Probably $\inf_\pi U(f,\pi)$.

Comment: @coffeemath
ohh so upper partition ?

Comment: What book is this from???

Comment: @copper.hat The statements mentioned are true without taking inf over partitions $\pi$. (So also hold on taking the infs.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answer is No.

Counter Example:

Define $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as follows $f(x)= 1$ if $x\in (\mathbb R - \mathbb Q ) \cap[0,1]$;  $f(x)= - 1$ if  $x\in  \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$. Then $|f|\in R[0,1]$(as being a continuous function) but $f \not \in R[0,1]$ (choosing partition one can conclude by definition).

Comment: I believe you intended to $f(x)$ to be negative one on one set. But otherwise, this was the counterexample that immediately came to my mind.

Comment: thats right; thanks;

Comment: Can you explain your comment "choosing partition one can conclude by definition" ? @Inquisitive

Comment: See the example in the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Riemann_integral):

Comment: I was thinking that weather a function $f^2$ is Riemann integrable implies $f$ is Riemann integrable or not? Now I've an answer, NO. Because, the above example from #lnquisitive gives me a counter-example. Thanks.